# Ajuda para realizar filtro de data inicial e data final em javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Estou tentando realizar um filtro entre a data inicial e final escolhida pelo usuário. Tenho alguns objetos que se parecem com:

```
let objetos = [
   {nome: 'teste01', data: '03/09/2019'}
   {nome: 'teste02', data: '03/10/2019'}
   {nome: 'teste03', data: '03/11/2019'}
   {nome: 'teste04', data: '03/12/2019'}
   {nome: 'teste05', data: '03/01/2020'}
]
```

O que eu espero é retornar por os objetos que contenham o seguinte por ex, os objetos com nome de teste01 e teste02 que estão dentro do intervalo de datas informado:

```
let dataInicial: string = '01/09/2019';
let dataFinal: string = '31/10/2019';
let objetosFiltrados = objetos.filter(result => {
   return result.data >= dataInicial && result.data <= dataFinal;
})
console.log(objetosFiltrados);
```

Porém quando eu executo isso ele me trás todos os registros, qual a forma correta de fazer isso por favor?

Comment: Você está usando o campo data no formato string, teria de converter para números ou data para fazer diferenciação de maior e menor. Também para trabalhar datas no formato dd/mm/yyyy você vai ter de desenvolver uma rotina para converter em um formato americano ou usar uma biblioteca tipo moment.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar este código que dá certo:

```js
let objetos = [
   {nome: 'teste01', data: '03/09/2019'},
   {nome: 'teste02', data: '03/10/2019'},
   {nome: 'teste03', data: '03/11/2019'},
   {nome: 'teste04', data: '03/12/2019'},
   {nome: 'teste05', data: '03/01/2020'}
]

function converteData(DataDDMMYY) {
    const dataSplit = DataDDMMYY.split("/");
    const novaData = new Date(parseInt(dataSplit[2], 10),
                  parseInt(dataSplit[1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(dataSplit[0], 10));
    return novaData;
}


let dataInicial = converteData('01/09/2019');
let dataFinal = converteData('31/10/2019');
let objetosFiltrados = objetos.filter(result => {
   return converteData(result.data) >= dataInicial && converteData(result.data) <= dataFinal;
})
console.log(objetosFiltrados);
```

Comment: Obrigado irmão, resolveu aqui para mim.